# How to disable bogus Visual Studio Code intellisense errors with C++ extension?

Tags: c++

I've started playing with using VSC for my C++ code. It's not standard C++ code, it's my own entire world. But I was hoping to try it out and see how it does (always a painful thing to change editors.) I'm not interested in it as an IDE just an editor, and having some on the fly error checking will be nice.

But, the C++ Intellisense guy doesn't understand safe enums apparently. I get an error for every use of such an enum, which makes it completely useless for finding errors because there are lots of them in most files.

I'm assuming this is a bug, but in the meantime, is there a way to disable just this bogus error?

Comment: voting to close as "not reproducible" since the answer is based on info that is not in the question, and there are better questions out there about setting up include paths for intellisense and excluding paths from it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the issue was that it was just going off and finding headers on its own. I have multiple output directories so that I can work on betas and still keep the previous working version(s) around. It was grabbing the previous version, and one of the things I'd done since then was a massive change of the whole code base over to new style enums. So it was seeing the old, non-safe enums.

Getting it to correctly include and ignore directories was a bit of an adventure but it seems to be working now.